# Selenium Error: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81 | My driver version is 81.0.4044.69

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Getting this error when trying to launch headed selenium session.

command I used was 
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please downgrade to Chromedriver 80 (which is stable version). Chromedriver 81 is still beta version and it supports chrome 81, I am sure you might have Chrome browser version 80.

You can download chrome 80 stable version from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/)

**Edit 1: Recommended**

Alternatively you can use [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/#description) which will take care of installing the latest driver on the fly. So you don't have to worry, each time when your browser get's updated/ newer version of driver is available.

Here is how you can install the `webdriver-manager` using `pip`.

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Once the `webdriver_manage` is installed successfully you can start using it in the script as shown below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit
```

The great part with this library is you can install any driver on the fly.

Comment: Glad that we are helpful. Please [upvote] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this for an Angular 8.2.x code project? Its the same error but the ng e2e command (run selenium tests) automatically looks for chromedriver 81.0.4044.20

Comment: not sure on angular, but try with `npm install -g webdriver-manager`